# Elixir/Phoenix timestamps local

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I have several schemas (Ecto.Schema)
and use *timestamps* for inserted_at, updated_at fields. But it defaults to the Ecto.DateTime and saves time in UTC. Is it possible to use local time, instead of UTC? I've checked the [Ecto.Schema](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#timestamps/1) but can't seem to find a way to default it to the local time, instead of the UTC. Example:

```
schema "orders" do

field :number_of_customers, :integer
field :completed, :boolean, default: false

timestamps
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to keep those in a different timezone so there may not be a way to change it but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Hey @JustMichael, I need it for the local machine, so when I insert into the db, it will insert according to my time, instead of utc.

Comment: I see. I guess you could either create a different datetime column and update it yourself or maybe play with database triggers to update those timestamps with every update or something like that but there has to be a better way but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Thanks @JustMichael, I'll try your suggestions. But yeah, it's kinda weird that there is no way to use local time, or at least specify the timezone, so then UTC will be +/- specific GMT.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#timestamps/1) you can do almost whatever you want with the `timestamps`.

Using options you can specify `:type` or you can even register custom function that will be called to generate those using `:autogenerate`.

However I would keep the timestamps in UTC, because this is a standard way. It is strange that it doesn't work for you. Calling `Ecto.DateTime.utc` shoud just get correct time zone information from the operating system and display correct time in UTC. If that is not the case, maybe your OS has incorrect time zone?